# Read data of type double from a text file in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, readfile, android-file

I want to read data of type double saved in a .txt file from a previously specified folder. I've implemented the following code to read data then put them in an array of type double named savg1. when I run my application , it going to crash and the application stop. I tried to debug the application step by step and found that crash happens when the code reaches to savg1[i] = Double.parseDouble(str).

```
public void filereader()
{

    InputStream is=this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.nums);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String str=null;
    int i=0;
    try
    {
        if (is !=null)
        {
            str=br.readLine();
            while (str != null) {
                savg1[i] = Double.parseDouble(str);
                i++;
                str=br.readLine();
            }
            is.close();
            br.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I am a newbie in Android developing so excuse me about my elementary question. Can anybody guide me how I can solve this problem?

Comment: One of the obvious reasons is that array is to small and you are getting index out of bound exception

Comment: my array length is 1000000 and my text file numbers are 1000000, I do not think so this was the problem.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: there is not any error, but when I run it on my phone, application stopped and exit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to read data from your file. Note that in this method each number should be in a separate line:

```
    double svg1[] = new double[10];

    try {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
        while (dis.available() > 0) {
            String test = dis.readLine();
            double a = Double.parseDouble(test);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use file scanner for reading double type data saved in a text file as bellow:

```
public void fileReader(){

   Scanner scan;
   File file = new File("resources\\scannertester\\data.txt");
   int idx = 0;
   try {
       scan = new Scanner(file);
       while(scan.hasNextDouble())
           savg1[idx++] = scan.nextDouble();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
   }
   scan.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how I should set the file path and where i should put my file? are this true? " C:\Users\Hanieh\Desktop\nums.txt :

Comment: Yes other wise check how to set path in scanner class